# Inner Join in TYPO3 Extbase

Tags: database, orm, inner-join, typo3

I have two tables `TableA` and `TableB`. These have to be joined together on the condition `TableA.Pid = TableB.Uid`.

The domain objects of the tables are created while building an extension using extension builder.

How do I achieve this in TYPO3?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: For the field `pid`, you can't do that out of the blue. `pid` is a reserved identifier for the *pages* table and cannot be freely used. Also, in an MVC scheme, the concept of INNER JOIN connections is not implemented as such. Unfortunately, IMHO. It was so easy to mess around in the old days ;).

**Here comes a more general approach** for those who are new to this:
Assuming, your table A is named *parent* and table B is named *child*.

- You can set the relations in the extension builder within the domain model dialogue. 
  Create two domain models: *Parent* and *Child*.
- Connect them by creating a relation *parentrecord* in the *Child* domain
  model which links to the model *Parent*.
- Make sure to create **both** as *aggregate root*

[image]

The *parentrecord* relation will be defined in your model  `my_ext/Classes/Domain/Model/Child.php`.
The `@var` annotation links it to the *parent* domain model:

```
/**
 * parentrecord
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\MyExt\Domain\Model\Parent
 */
protected $parentrecord;
```

All children of a parent record (e.g., parent uid = 42) can then be retrieved from your controller like that:

```
$this->childRepository->findByParentrecord(42);
```

This is an abbreviated answer. Note that your custom Extbase code might not work out of the box, but don't get frustrated - It will work eventually. 
As for the `pid` thing, I will try to help you on your related [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928551/mapping-to-pages-table-from-extbase-in-typo3-6-1).