# Mapping to "pages" table from Extbase in TYPO3 6.1

Tags: typo3, extbase

I created an extension with a domain model `Message`. This model has a relation m:n with the TYPO3 `pages` (the one which has the details of the pages, like title, issite_root etc) table. However, by using the `mapping to existing tables` option, it gives me `type` error saying page :

```
The configured type field for table "pages" is of type int(11) unsigned
This means the type field can not be used for defining the record type. 
You have to configure the mappings yourself if you want to map to this
table or extend the correlated class
```

So I just create the relation without mapping, so that I can later map it from `setup.txt`.

[image]

The I created model `Pages` in `MyExt/Classes/Domain/Model/` with all the getters/setters and repository in `MyExt/Classes/Domain/Repository/`.

In my setup.txt I did this:

```
config.tx_extbase {
    persistence{
        enableAutomaticCacheClearing = 1
        updateReferenceIndex = 0
        classes {
        Tx_Playfield_Domain_Model_Pages {
            mapping {
                    tableName = pages
                columns {
                                uid.mapOnProperty               = uid
                                pid.mapOnProperty               = pid
                                sorting.mapOnProperty           = sorting
                                title.mapOnProperty             = title
                                subtitle.mapOnProperty          = subtitle
                            }
                }
            }
      }
    }
}
```

But when I try to access the Pages model I created,

`var_dump($this->pagesRepository->findByUid(74));`

its searching for `tx_playfield_domain_model_pages` which does not exists,  it shows

```
Table 'typo3.tx_playfield_domain_model_pages' doesn't exist: SELECT tx_playfield_domain_model_pages.* FROM tx_playfield_domain_model_pages WHERE tx_playfield_domain_model_pages.uid = '74' LIMIT 1
```

What am I missing here?

**Update**

After following http://t3-developer.com/extbase-fluid/cheats-extbase/model/tabelle-pages-in-extbase/ suggested by @Michael I get an `empty result` from `$this->pagesRepository->findByUid(74)`

`setup.txt` is loading. I did this to check it:

```
plugin.tx_playfield{
settings{
 temp=yes
}
}
```

And this is being accessed from my controller.

Comment: setup.txt looks good to me. How is your model defined in MyExt/Classes/Domain/Model/Pages.php? Did you check that setup.txt is actually loaded at runtime (use the TS Object Browser http://stackoverflow.com/a/6671818/283854)? Did you try setting the same stuff using  `config.tx_playfield` instead of `config.tx_extbase`?

Comment: Yes. I updated, It seems the setup.txt is loaded but however, extbase does not know its mapped. 

I also tried `config.tx_playfield` and it does not work !

Comment: Btw: Better use `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($var, 'Name');` for debugging purposes. It has a lot of advantages.

Comment: There's a working Extbase implementation of pages/tt_content in the extension [pw_teaser](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/pw_teaser) ([source code](https://github.com/TYPO3-svn-archive/pw_teaser)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible that you didn't create the *Pages* domain model (within the extension builder or not at all)? The file `my_ext/Classes/Domain/Model/Pages.php` needs to exist. Check that your "Pages" domain model has the property *Map to existing table* set to *pages*, it should look like that:

[image]

I don't know where exactly your error is, but I did some more tinkering in the extension builder and made it work. You can probably find out by comparing your extension *playfield* to my temporary extension *testfield*: [Download it here (updated)](http://www.divshare.com/download/24340314-a67).

---

Btw, you don't need to map properties that you do not want to be displayed in the frontend unless they are named differently.

```
        mapping {
            tableName = pages
            columns {
                title.mapOnProperty = title
                subtitle.mapOnProperty = subtitle
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes. I initially did add `Pages` from extension builder, but as that was showing weird errors, I created one myself. However, your extensions `testfield` is just what I wanted. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I did not map it from Extension builder initially, that was the error. But now I did and with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962619/map-to-existing-tables-in-extension-builder-showing-weird-issues-in-typo3 as a reference was able to make it work

Comment: Nice! This even works in 2022 with TYPO3 10.4!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to write the mapping with camel case letters (the class name). Although [this post](http://t3-developer.com/extbase-fluid/cheats-extbase/model/tabelle-pages-in-extbase/) is in German, I think the code might help you. The author added some fields he is going to use to the class and also added a mapping in the typoscript of the extension (see the example code there). The most important part of the German text is that this example there was designed only to read from the db. If you want to create new pages using the model, you have (at least) to add the TCA and setters in the model class to make it work.

Comment: Thank you for the resource. That was pretty much what I did too. Now its just showing me an `empty result` when I do `$this->pageRepository->findAll()->toArray()`

Comment: It seems like Extbase is not aware of the mapping and thus showing `NULL` results