# "Map to existing tables" in Extension builder showing weird issues in TYPO3

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

In my extension `MyExt`, I mapped the model `Page` to `pages` table in TYPO3. Firstly it shows me the `type mismatch` error, I anyhow went ahead and saved it.

The following things happen:

- My Page tree becomes like this:

[image]

- My New Record Form shows only the UIDs and not the titles:

[image]

- My Page Edit becomes like this:
  [image]

In my `MyExt/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt` I have this:

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes {
    Tx_MyExt_Domain_Model_Page {
        mapping {
            tableName = pages
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a bug ? Or something i'm doing wrong ?

This is my `/Domain/Model/Page.php` , just a glimpse of it.

```
class Page extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity
{

    /**
     * uid
     * @var int
     * @validate NotEmpty
     */
    protected $uid;

    /**
     * title
     * @var string
     * @validate NotEmpty
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * __construct
     *
     * @return Page
     */
    public function __construct() {
        //Do not remove the next line: It would break the functionality
        $this->initStorageObjects();
    }

   /**
    * Returns the title
    *
    * @return string $title
   */
  public function getTitle(){
    return $this->title;
  }

}
```

My `/Domain/Repository/PageRepository.php` is

```
class PageRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository {

}
```

Comment: Showe us a model and repository declaration (at least beginning) for you `Tx_MyExt_Domain_Model_Page`

Comment: Yes sure. I added them. They both have `namespaces`

Comment: Quite a funky issue. As I do not have an answer myself, I am keen on the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just delete the whole `$TCA['pages']` section from the file `my_ext/ext_tables.php`, or comment it out.

If set, it overrides most default TCA settings from the TYPO3 core with values from your extension. You probably don't need custom settings for that.

Comment: Haa, that's interesting. Working now. Thank you so much :)