# TYPO3 create frontend user

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

In my service class I have

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $frontendUserRepository;

/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager
 * @inject
 */
protected $persistenceManager;
```

And in a function:

```
$objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager');
$this->frontendUserRepository = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Domain\\Repository\\FrontendUserRepository');
$frontendUser = new FrontendUser();
$frontendUser->setUsername($bla);
$frontendUser->setPassword($bliep);
$this->frontendUserRepository->add($frontendUser);
$this->persistenceManager = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\PersistenceManager');
$this->persistenceManager->persistAll();
```

Then I get error

> Table 'dbname.tx_extbase_domain_model_frontenduser' doesn't exist

How can I store the new user in the 'fe_users' table?

Comment: does this help? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928551/mapping-to-pages-table-from-extbase-in-typo3-6-1

Comment: I see there something like

`config.tx_extbase.persistence.classesTx_Extname_Domain_Model_Member.mapping.tableName=fe_users`

But I don't have a model?

Comment: Thx for the direction. I guess I need a model for a mapping, so I decided for now to insert the new user directly with a Doctrine-Dbal insert query.

Comment: Extbase has a model for FE-Users. You can use that.

Comment: But, I am not sure, it looks like you need to make a own model, (extend the FE-users model), to be able to map.

Comment: Your error will normally be solved with the solution David and Michiel mentioned, if your typoscript is included correct. I often use file ext_typoscript_setup.txt in my extension to include such configuration automaticly at rootline.

Answer (score 2):

Make a table mapping in your TypoScript setup extbase configuration:

```
config.tx_extbase {
    persistence {
        classes {
            TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser {
                mapping {
                    tableName = fe_users
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have extended the frontenduser, but a mapping seems to get ignored in a service class. I guess the typoscript needs to be loaded there. However I think after trying a while to just use Doctrine. Thx!